# pymodm do not recognised the objects of a model

Tags: python, mongoengine, pymodm

I have started using pymodm in my project (https://github.com/ypriverol/biocontainers-backend/blob/master/biocontainers/common/models.py). All CRUD operations work very well.

However, when I try to retrieve the list of objects for a specific MongoModel using the objects call:

```
    tool_versions_dic = MongoToolVersion.objects.all()
```

I got this error:

```
    AttributeError: type object 'MongoToolVersion' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: Is this command working? `MongoToolVersion.manager.mongo_all_tool_versions()`

Comment: you mean this line: https://github.com/ypriverol/biocontainers-backend/blob/master/biocontainers/common/models.py#L89 . Yes it works. I'm new to pymodm and python in general. Sorry if the question is obvious

Comment: Probably, i dint explain we’ll. the manager call works. But the objects.all() not. Why?